# How to insert an array of JSON in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to insert data from nodejs to mongodb using Mongoose. The Mongoose schema for inserting data is as shown

```
const NoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    active: String,
    institution_name:String,
    recommended_for:String,
    Medicine:[{
        medicine_name:String,
        grade_of_evidence:String,
        grade_of_recommendation:String
    }],
        free_text_recommendation:[{
        title:String,
        comment:String
    }]


},
{
    timestamps:true
});
```

I have created a separate controller file to handle CRUD operations. The code below is for **POST**

```
const Note = require("../models/note.model");
exports.create = (req,res)=>{
const note = new Note({
    active: req.body.active || "Unititled Note",
    institution_name:req.body.institution_name,
    recommended_for:req.body.recommended_for,
    Medicine:[{
        medicine_name:req.body.Medicine.medicine_name,
        grade_of_evidence:req.body.Medicine.grade_of_evidence,
        grade_of_recommendation:req.body.Medicine.grade_of_recommendation
        }],
    free_text_recommendation:[{
        title:req.body.free_text_recommendation.title,
        comment:req.body.free_text_recommendation.comment
    }]
});
note.save().then(
    data=>{
        res.send(data);

    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occured while creating note"
        });
    });

};
```

I used the Google Chrome REST Client to insert some mock data according to the schema defined in mongoose. The list of objects for **Medicine** and **free_text_recommendation** does not get inserted, only the id for those 2 gets inserted as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoSD7.png)

All the other data such as "active","institution_name" could be successfully entered, I am having trouble only with the list of json.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `new mongoose.Schema` when you modeling for subdocuments.
use this model, it will work for you.

```
const MedicineArr = new mongoose.Schema({
 medicine_name:String,
        grade_of_evidence:String,
        grade_of_recommendation:String
})

const free_text_recommendationArr = new mongoose.Schema({
            title:String,
        comment:String

})

const NoteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    active: String,
    institution_name:String,
    recommended_for:String,
    Medicine: [MedicineArr],
    free_text_recommendation: [free_text_recommendationArr]
},
{
    timestamps:true
});
```

Comment: How do I form a request body in such a case?